# How to access referenced table in a n:m relation in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

I have got a Database like this:

```
    users
    -id

    user_cars
    -user_id
    -car_id

    cars
    -id
    -model
    -color
```

So a user can have multiple cars, and detailed information about the cars are in a big cars table. I also created the models with the relationships.

```
class User 
has_many :user_cars

class User_car
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :cars

class Car
has_many :user_cars
```

Now I want to access the information for all the cars for one user. My first approach would be to get at least one information (i.e. color) from the cars table.

I tried this one, just as an example for accessing the middle table:

```
@user_id = current_user.user_cars.find(1).user_id
```

works! But when I try to access the cars table I always get an error.

```
@color = current_user.user_cars.cars.find(1).color

undefined method `cars' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xaf92e8c>
```

So I think Im doin something easy very wrong...

When I know how to get access to the third table, I have to do it in that fashion, that I only get results for the user and not just only the first entry, maybe you guys can help me with that aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your example by the way is that belongs_to should be singular.  Also, your order was wrong.

```
@color = current_user.user_cars.find_by_car_id(1).car.color
```

You should rewrite this to use a [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) association:

```
class User 
has_many :user_cars
has_many :cars, :through => :user_cars

class UserCar
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :car
```

You can then access the cars by doing:

```
current_user.cars
```

And the color by doing:

```
@color = current_user.cars.find_by_car_id(1).color
```

**EDIT**

After some debugging, it turns out that the Car model has a class property.  Class is a reserved word in ruby.  Be careful with naming your attributes!

Comment: same as above... didnt work... could you aswell copy all of my code so that I can see when to use cars or without s.
The Classnames are singular and Tablenames plural in my case.

Comment: Your User_car class should be UserCar.  In what way does it not work?  What error?

Comment: undefined method `private_method_defined?' for "blue":String

is the error I get after changing everything to your version

Comment: That implies to me that it is indeed getting the color.  Try running a rails console (rails c in the terminal) and typing the following: `User.first.cars.first.color`  If that returns a color then the error is with what you are doing on the data and not the retrieval of the data.

Comment: ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > User.first.cars.first.id


  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  Car Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "user_cars" ON "cars"."id" = "user_cars"."car_id" WHERE "user_cars"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `private_method_defined?' for "C":String

Comment: That is odd.  Try doing `User.first.cars` and post the response as there is nothing wrong with the association.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5728/discussion-between-gazler-and-sebastian-oberste-vorth)

Comment: This answer is *WRONG* as `current_user.user_cars.find(1).car.color` will FIND the UserCar model by it's OWN ID (id from association table), rather the car ID. If you want to do it like this it should say `current_user.user_cars.where(:car_id => 1).first.car.color`.

Answer (score 1):

Without has_many :through associations:

```
@color = current_user.user_cars.where(:car_id => 1).first.color
```

With them:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cars, :foreign_key => :user_id, :class_name => "UserCar", :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :cars, :through => :user_cars
end

class UserCar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cars, :foreign_key => :car_id, :class_name => "UserCar", :inverse_of => :car
  has_many :cars, :through => :user_cars
end

@color = current_user.cars.find(1).color
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

- :through defines a shortcut
- :inverse_of defines a method (association) which represents current model in :class_name model
- :class_name defines which model should be represented by :user_cars
- :foreign_key tells which column in the target model's table represents current model (in table user_cars (or users_cars, depends on how you define the association, i think it should be user_cars in this example.. and users_cars for `has_and_belongs_to_many`)

Details on those are in the link above.

Comment: sorry didnt work... maybe it because of car/cars user/users and so on... could that be the reason? can you try to copy the User class as well, so that i can see when to use car and when to use cars...

The Classnames are singular and Tablenames plural in my case

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth I've expanded the examples a little. Model names should be singular and table names should be plural (it can be overridden by set_table_name :table_name in each model if you want, but this is the convention), so you have it right.